# Subtracting a list from a nested list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to subtract a list from nested list.
For example,

```
x=[[1, 2, 4], [0, 3, 2]]
y=[2.3333333333333335, 1.6666666666666667]
```

The expected output is something like this

```
x-y=[[-1.33333335, -0.333333335, 1.66666],
[-1.666666,1.33333333,0.3333333326]]
```

I tried to use zip function but didn't have success. Any ideas how can I do that? I am not allowed to use numpy by the way. Thank you in advance

Comment: You should show what you tried and what happened as a result.

Comment: Maybe: `[[z-y for z in x] for x, y in zip(lst, lst2)]`?

Comment: Your question would be much better with an explanation of what you want to achieve, an example with simple, readable values, and the code you wrote and how it fails to give you the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List comprehension:

```
x=[[1, 2, 4], [0, 3, 2]]
y=[2.3333333333333335, 1.6666666666666667]
print([[z-y_y for z in x_x] for x_x, y_y in zip(x, y)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach using nested loop:

```
x = [[1, 2, 4], [0, 3, 2]]
y = [2.3333333333333335, 1.6666666666666667]
for i in range(0, len(x)):
    for j in range(0, len(x[i])):
        x[i][j] -= y[i]
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test = [list(xval-y for xval in xlist) for xlist, y in zip(x,y)]
```

### Output

```
0:[-1.3333333333333335, -0.3333333333333335, 1.6666666666666665]
1:[-1.6666666666666667, 1.3333333333333333, 0.33333333333333326]
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question is also valid for answers and text outputs.